# Simplification of $\cos^4(x) + \sin^4(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\begin{align}
(\sin x)^4+(\cos x)^4
&= (1-\cos2x)^2/4 + (1+\cos2x)^2/4\\
&= (1-2\cos2x+(\cos2x)^2+1+2\cos2x+(\cos2x)^2)/4\\
&= (1+(\cos2x)^2)/2\\
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster way:
\begin{align}
\sin^4x+\cos^4x&=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x\\
&=1-\frac12(2\sin x\cos x)^2=1-\frac12\sin^22x \\[1ex]
&=1-\frac12\frac{1-\cos 4x}2=\frac{3+\cos 4x}4.
\end{align}

Comment: That's exactly the answer I found in other posts. I just wonder why the double angle formula couldn't arrive at the same conclusion at yours...

Comment: That's because you didn't go till the end of the linearisation process($\cos^22x=\frac{1+\cos4x}2$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos2y=\cos^2y-\sin^2y=1-2\sin^2y=2\cos^2y-1$$
$$\implies\sin^2y= \dfrac{1-\cos2y}2 ,\cos^2y=\dfrac{1+\cos2y}2$$

First $y=x$

Apply the same $(y=2x)$ for $\cos^22x=\dfrac{1+\cos4x}2$

Comment: An error:

$$\cos^2(y) = \frac{1 + \cos(2y)}{2}$$

What you have suggests $\sin^2y = \cos^2y$, which is patently false. Neglecting, of course, that you're not at all addressing OP's question. Where does $x$ even come from in your answer? It's impossible to follow your logic.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer, That was a typo. I introduced to $y$ to replace it with $x,2x$ one by one

Comment: Okay, now I see where you're coming from. Though personally I would elaborate a little more in your answer to demonstrate the utility of this myself. A little elaboration and explanation can go a long way in terms of an answer's usefulness, because if it's impenetrable for other MSE users (IIRC I and someone else had like issues with another of your answers tonight) it's probably not very helpful to a question's OP in case of questions like these. Just my two cents.

Comment: thanks lab, I get it and I make it thru now.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^4+\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{2^4}\left(\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)^4+\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^4\right)
$$

but

$$
(a+b)^4+(a-b)^4 = 2 (a^4+6 a^2 b^2+b^4)
$$

hence

$$
\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x = \frac{1}{2^3}\left(2\cos(4x)+6\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\cos(4x)+3\right)
$$